# How to exchange time between C and Python

Tags: python, c, time

I'm writing some C code that needs to embed the current time in its (binary) output file.  Later, this file will be read by some other C code (possibly compiled for different architecture) and/or some python code.  In both cases calculations may be required on the time.

What I'd like to know is:

1. How do I get current UTC time in C?  Is time() the write call?
2. What format should I write this to file in?  ASN1? ISO?
3. How do I convert to that format?
4. How do I read that format in C and Python and convert it into something useful?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

Comment: both `time_t` and `time()` itself aren't portable. `time_t` might simply be implemented as a different type, and `time()` is only defined as time since epoch. Even though this is generally speaking since the Unix epoch, implementations are free to choose their own.

Comment: Ok - if you're going to downvote and vote to close, could you comment as to why?

Comment: What Daniel suggested is the most portable way. Combine that with [`getdate`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/General-Time-String-Parsing.html#General-Time-String-Parsing) on the C side and you should be good to go.

Comment: You can store time in UNIX time format.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions at once, and you appear to not have tried to find an answer to any of these yourself (which is a good reason for a downvote). Some of your questions appear to not be answerable within a few paragraphs or appear to be a matter of individual style, also it is unclear what programming language you actually refer to (altogether this would satisfy a decision to vote-to-close). Please be more specific in your question and show what you have tried to find an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following C code to get a suitable date output:

```
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm *now;
  char timestamp[80];

  time(&rawtime);
  now = gmtime(&rawtime);
  strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", now);
```

Then use the following python to read it:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Variations on the format work, as long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [rfc 3339 datetime format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) (a profile of ISO8601). It avoids many pitfalls of unconstrained ISO8601 timestamps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  char buf[21];
  time_t ts = time(NULL);

  struct tm *tp = gmtime(&ts);
  if (tp == NULL || tp->tm_year > 8099 || tp->tm_year < 0) {
    perror("gmtime");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tp) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "strftime returned 0\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  exit(puts(buf) != EOF ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

#### Output

```
2014-12-20T11:08:44Z
```

To read it in Python:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> dt = datetime.strptime('2014-12-20T11:08:44Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
>>> dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
>>> print(dt)
2014-12-20 11:08:44+00:00
```